# Where do i find the JOSSO database configuration file?

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, josso

We have Josso authentication on our website and recently we changed the mysql server and now are in the process of upgrading all the mysql hostnames, usernames and passwords in the database configuration files.

However, a critical component of our site - Josso is still nonfunctional because we have no idea where the database configuration file of josso exists.

I would really appreciate anything that helps me figure out where this is located.

Here is the URL of the site through which it is trying to access Josso :

https://www.mysite.com:8443/josso/signon/usernamePasswordLogin.do;jsessionid=97FACC232630E8A8B93B141A67FBE01C

Edit : We are using Tomcat 6 located under /etc/tomcat6 and also has a server.xml file inside it. I could not find anything relevant related to josso db settings there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully you've already figured this out, but this should be documented for others.  This documentation is available at [the JOSSO wiki, database section](http://www.josso.org/confluence/display/JOSSO1/Database+Setup).

Assuming JOSSO 1.8.x, there is either a file in $TOMCAT_HOME/lib, which is where we have our configuration, or in $TOMCAT_HOME/webapps/josso/WEB-INF/classes called *josso-gateway-db-stores.xml*.  If you cannot find this file, look for *josso-gateway-config.xml* which will have the various import statements for the other parts of the gateway configuration.  The store configuration contains elements which reference a **dsJndiName**.  This is the datasource that is either defined in you META-INF/context.xml file or in Tomcat's server.xml as a **Resouce** element.